# Rails after_create proc no receiver given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have started a project in Ruby on Rails and using devise for user registration. I am having difficulty getting my head around why the following is not working:

```
# After create hook to send passwrd reset instructions
after_create(&:send_reset_password_instructions)
```

I am wondering whether this is a specific implementation issue with the devise method to reset the password information, or I am doing something incorrect. Probably the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't pass your method as block proc, but as regular argument:

```
after_create :send_reset_password_instructions
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that the send_reset_password_instructions method needed to be called on an object, i.e. as a block `after_create { |user| user.send_reset_password_instructions }` but I wanted to try out the other syntax `&:`

Answer (score 1):

As supplemental information to Marek's answer:

When you give `{ |user| user.send_reset_password_instructions }` block to the `after_create` method, it becomes a `Proc` object of `#arity == 1`, where as `&:send_reset_password_instructions` becomes `arity == -1`.  In fact, `#arity` is used to determine how a the hooked is called.  Refer:  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4a68792df7f2cecf9e6d9ddb18dfe761f553eb2a/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L447

So, in general, when you define hooks for callbacks, you should not use the `&:method_name` format.